# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner Version=10.5.3700.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have a web application with visual studio 2008 and crystal report 2008 and all thing is fine

BUT

when i installed SAP crystal report 2010 , my be it crash with CR 2008

when i run my APP i get this message
***Could not load file or assembly  CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner  Version=10.5.3700.0***

i do some solutions
1 - i open web.config file and delete the row of CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner  - my app run fine but reports not working

when i add this row again my app not running

please . i do alot of research about this problems but no HOPE

thanks for ur time

Comment: so where i can find cr ddls in windows ( windows server 2008 x64 ) or can i put these dlls liberaries manually in my windows ??

Answer (score 1):

In Vs 2003 the Runtime of Crystal reports was bundled in the program setup when you create the installer and installed, but with vs 2005 and later you have to install it.
I think here you can find the msi

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917

The dll version of the Runtime that ships with vs is different from the various version of Crystal reports, so you have to install the right one

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that installing the new version of Crystal Reports wiped your previous assemblies out of the GAC and replaced them with a newer version. From [SAP](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567):

> As each version of Crystal Reports has its' own specific runtime which
>   must be correctly deployed, it is critical that the deployed runtime
>   be in agreement with the Crystal Reports assemblies for Visual Studio
>   .NET referenced in your project.

Your error looks like it is trying to find a DLL from Crystal Reports 10.5 and as the above link suggests, it does not like having differing versions of crystal reports running side by side.

Comment: so where i can find CR dlls in my windows ( windows server 2008 x64)

Comment: another thing .. when i open c:/windows/assembly i found all cr dlls except crystaldecision.vsdesigner   why ?